# One form with two buttons

Tags: html, forms, http

I have a form with two buttons and I also have a parameter, which takes 2 different values depending on what button was pressed. 
If I write something like this

```
<form>
     <input type="hidden" name="method" value="saveXml"/>
     <input type="submit" name="save" value="SAVE"/>

     <input type="hidden" name="method" value="cancelled"/>
     <input type="submit" name="back" value="BACK"/> 
</form>
```

the parameter "method" is always passed to the server with value "saveXml".

And due to other conditions of the task I can't put these buttons in 2 separated forms. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change buttons to hyperlinks.
2. Make hyperlinks invoke different javascript functions.
3. Specific JS function will submit form with the value you specify.

Other than that - you can place only one 'hidden' input and change it's value on the fly with Javascript depending which button has been clicked. This you have to detect also in javascript. In this case submit is also done with JS not by button click.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems I really need js here.

Comment: Sorry for annoying, but NO, you don't need js and even hidden fields. Check my comment below my answer. Speaking in pseudocode (to describe only logics/algorithm), you can do: `IF( $submit = 'save' ) DO save_your_xml_class ELSEIF ( $submit = 'back' ) dont_save_and_perform_back_class`. This way you determine what class to execute based on received value. And you need only 2 submit buttons with different names, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

In your form post values, if the user clicks the `save` button, it will have a field with `save` and a value of `SAVE`.

If the user clicks on the `back` button, it will have a value of `BACK`.

You don't need hidden fields to do this.

When clicking submit buttons, the browser will only post the value of the input the user clicked to the server.  (If you click `save`, then `back` will not be posted, and vise versa)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the value of parameter I want to pass and the name of button are different and I need to pass not 'SAVE' but 'saveXml'(when SAVE is pressed) and the same with other button.

Comment: If you have control over the receiving end, you can change it to look for that instead.  If not, then some crafty javascript solution is required.

Answer (score -1):

@Matthew gives correct advice.
Here is sample php code (consider it as PSEUDOCODE, just to understand logics):

[EDITED to reflect logics, not PHP example with javascript history.back(-1)]

```
if( $_POST['save'] ) :
    // your saveXml case
    ...
else if ($_POST['back']) :
    // your back case
    ...
```

This way save will be processed (XML will be saved) only if you press "Save" button and back will be processed only if you press 'Back' button. No javascript, no hidden fields.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't use php. I use Struts and depending on the value of passed parameter "method" it decides what method from Action class to execute

Comment: It would be great if you specify this in question). Anyway, if you submit your form, it will send ALL values, POST will have all 4 vars (inputs) and 2 of them have the same name and different values - problem is here. I'm not familiar with Struts and PHP example is just to illustate logics - if we speak in general PSEUDOCODE format I would suggest logics like: IF( $submit = 'save' ) DO save_your_xml ELSEIF ( $submit = 'back' ) dont_save_and_perform_back. These way you don't need ajavascript and even hidden fields, you choose what class to execute based on variable you receive (button pressed).

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but i do not understand your answer. What language are you using? What interprets/check the condition in 'IF' ? I do not know how you are doing 'IF' without javascript or php. Is this PHP?

Comment: Oh, c'mon, guys.. I'm learning Struts now just to help you ) Any programming language has basic condition checking. Usually it is called IF,ELSE,ELSEIF. The syntax may differ, of course. I wrote a PSEUDOCODE (refer to Wikipedia for details if you are not familiar with this concept), it has nothing to do with specific language syntax, it's just a MODEL, algorythm, logics. I've done some RTFM, here's how it looks in Struts: `<s:if test="#myobj.key = 'value'"> //do smth </s:if>`. Is it ok now?